# Проблема с float и масштаб сцены unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

В процессе разработки иногда сталкивался что изначально был выбран размер для объектов на сцене, приходилось scale у трансформы уменьшать вплоть до 0.00002.

В связи с этим начали появляться проблемы с округлением float, неточное позиционирование, продёргивание моделек на сцене, провал через коллайдеры и прочее.

Вопрос такое - можно как то поменять сейчас масштаб сцены, когда она уже заполнена разными предметами, просто, грубо говоря, увеличить у всего скейл в 100 раз, чтобы соотношения остались прежними, камера это всё видела как прежде, однако пропали артефакты связанные с округлением float.

И дело не только в скейле. На сцене много вещей с координатами типа
-0.009335434
Как то это дело перевести в адекватные числа, оставив прежнее соотношение.

Answer (score 0):

Есть простое решение, не знаю, поможет вам оно или нет.

1. Создаете на сцене пустой *GameObject*.
2. Выделив все объекты и засовываете в новосозданный *GameObject* (делаете их чайлдами)
3. Увеличиваете `scale` этого *GameObject* до необходимого вам значения.
4. Вытаскиваете все игровые объекты из этого *GameObject*. (не обятельно, или обязательно)

Не уверен, но вроде должно помочь.